# Changing Firefox's memory of page titles

Tags: firefox

Every few hours, my company makes me click through a "just a reminder, we're monitoring your Internet use" web page when I try to visit a public website. Generally, this is not a problem. However, the reminder page's title sometimes becomes the page title that Firefox saves, as seen here:

[image: Title for "slacker.com" is "Notification: Policy Acknowledgement"]

I'd like to make "Slacker radio" the title for `http://slacker.com`. How can I overwrite or reset Firefox's memory of the page title associated with a given URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the title manually by changing it in `places.sqlite`. This file can be found here (the string before `.default` is randomly generated):

`C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ppbajnz5.default`

You can use [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to open the file:

[image: SQLite window]

Comment: I won't be in front of the computer that's having the issue for another week or so, but this looks good. On another note, where'd you get your avatar from? I saw the same one on a [dd-wrt forum post](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=512851&sid=bc355ee91e4a7d0730ca9d25f0e79b30#512851) that really helped me out.

Comment: @LordTorgamus I don't remember where I got it (it's from 3+ years ago) I'm not that guy on the dd-wrt forums.